# how to display current area during a Modify interaction?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I have a requirement to display the current area of a Polygon *during* a [Modify interaction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Modify-Modify.html).
I know how to listen for the `modifyend` event and, when it fires, calculate the area and display it in an overlay, but looking at the documentation, the interaction doesn't fire any other event **while** the vertex of a polygon is being dragged. I tried using the `handleDragEvent` function in the options of the [Pointer interaction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Pointer-PointerInteraction.html) (which is the superclass of the Modify interaction) like this:

```
this.modify = new Modify({
   handleDragEvent: (ev)=>{
       console.log('drag event', ev);
       // compute the new area and display it in an overlay
       return true;
  },
  features: this.select.getFeatures(),
});
```

While the above does fire, defining the `handleDragEvent` in this way has the effect of not allowing the modification of the Polygon at all (I experimented returning both `true` and `false` and the effect is the same).

I was able to achieve the same effect in the [Draw interaction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Draw-Draw.html) by calculating the area and displaying it in an overlay inside the `geometryFunction` but I don't know how to achieve the same in the Modify interaction.

Any ideas? Code that simply fires when the vertex of a polygon is moved and has access to the feature / geometry being modified is enough, I can take it from there.

Comment: It can be calculated as the modified geometry is styled and while that calculated value could be displayed in an overlay it would be more efficient to include it in the style.  This example shows radius of an equivalent circle based on polygon area  https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-forked-wz0fy

Comment: @Mike the example updates the radius of the circle only at the end of the modification, not while the circle is expanded

Comment: It does not attempt to show radius in the initial draw.  There should be a continuous update if you modify after that.